# Enable Query string per controller in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

Is there a way to enable query string in just one controller or for one function.
For example, I want to use query string in search function, and segments in every other.

Is there a way to do this?

Can I do something like this:

```
$this->config->set_item('uri_protocol', 'PATH_INFO');
$this->config->set_item('enable_query_strings', TRUE);
```

Comment: Why do you want to use query strings in the first place? You can pass data the CI way using segments rather than query strings. example.com?first=cheese&second=pizza is done like this the CI way - example.com/controller/method/cheese/pizza.

Comment: p.s. welcome to stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is by parsing the server query string like so.

```
$get_data = array();

parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $get_data);
```

This will leave you with a very insecure array full of data, so you should use CI's security class to make it more secure; so like;

```
$get_data = $this->security->xss_clean($get_data);
```

This will not mean that routing works via GET, only allow you to get the GET vars safely.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer saved me from several really bad alternatives.